# How to mock a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, tf.keras

I would like to test a function that takes a `tf.keras` model and performs some operations on it. Example function illustrating the problem:

```
def func(model, x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        output = model(x)
        # do some additional stuff with output
        gradient = np.array(tape.gradient(output, x))
        # do some additional stuff with gradient
        return gradient
```

I wonder what the best idea to mock `model` is.
Possible solutions:

1. Use a small network with set weights. This one is easiest to implement but
   a) It takes a longer time to calculate than a simple mock.
   b) It's hard to control what is returned by the model.
2. Mock using unit test or `pytest`. This one will straight up fail because no computation graph is created which would link `x` and `output`.
3. Move `tape.gradient(output, x)` to another function, then, during tests, mock this function and `model(x)` using unit test or pytest. I think this one is the best but it makes `func` less readable (especially if more tf specific elements have to be moved to various other functions).

Is there a better way? Ideally, I would like to:

1. Express that this model for a given input `x` returns a given output `y`.
2. Express that the gradient of a given output `y` w.r.t. a given input `x` is `z`.
3. Express that the gradient of a given output `y` w.r.t. a given layer `l` is `l'`.
4. Minimize necessary modifications to `func`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Are you trying to assert that the model can perform to some degree?